# list box item issue when navigate by using back key

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a list box and when clicked on the list item it goes to its detail page.and when i pressed the back key from detail page and after that if i again clicked the sale list item does not navigate to the detail page but if i clicked other items in the list it navigate to the corresponding detail page.
Actually i am not reloading the list box on  back key pressed .I just pop up it from the back stack.if I reload the list box the issue is not there.Is there any solution for this issue .below is my code.

ListViewPage

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailPage.isBackkeyPressed && list != null)
    {
        DetailPage.isBackkeyPressed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ListDetails(); //Reloading the page if list is empty
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        (Application.Current as App).obj_list = list[listBox.SelectedIndex];
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); //Navigate to detail page
    }
}
```

DetailPage

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    isBackkeyPressed = true;//flag  for check if back key is pressed
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unset the `SelectedIndex`, by setting it to `-1`, like this:

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        (Application.Current as App).obj_list = list[listBox.SelectedIndex];
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); //Navigate to detail page

        listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or handle the tap event on each item (set in the ItemTemplate) instead of handling SelectionChanged.

Comment: Can't do command-binding for tap handlers ;-) (But can for SelectionChanged, with ToolkitExtensions http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ToolkitExtensions)

Comment: I was referring to the Silverlight Toolkit's GestureHandler for Tap. But regardless, the Tap *event* in Mango is still a *event* , meaning you can't directly CommandBind it, putting us back to square one. (And I prefer remaining clean of System.Interactivity because it changes every version)